# What happens when Fate Cards become Expendable in Ivory Edition?

Tags: legend-of-the-five-rings

If a Fate card gains the Expendable keyword, as in the example of [Holding Cells](http://imperialassembly.com/oracle/#cardid=10733,#hashid=32635fe671ac1eed778354b03b9f4495,#cardcount=0) with [Kobi Sensei](http://imperialassembly.com/oracle/#cardid=11647,#hashid=eb8825d7095c927657a2a44968f84390,#cardcount=0), does playing the card form hand trigger the Expendable keyword?

Would this affect a Kata or Allegiance with Expendable, as they do enter play?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From rulebook:
"Expendable: After a card with the Expendable
keyword is destroyed, the player who
controlled it last draws a card."

Action cards are not destroyed after beeing played so keyword isn't triggered.

Answer (score 0):

my understanding of it is that the holding cell isn't a Kolat card.  It creates a Kolat Battle.  The only cards currently which are Kolat are:

Oboro, the Liar
Yasuki Jire
Yasuki Makoto
Yoritomo Yusuke